# How to store downloaded images in to android SD card

Tags: android

Hi I am developing app which downloads the images from the web site
and then i am displaying them as slide show.  Now I want save the
downloaded images into my SD card please help me.

My current attempt is:

```
File imageFileFolder = new File(Environment
               .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test");
imageFileFolder.mkdir();
File imageFileName = new File(imageFileFolder, date
               + pBean.getAuthorName());

InputStream fis = pBean.getInputStream();

byte[] data = new byte[fis.available()];
fis.read(data);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFileName);
fos.write(data);
fos.close();
fis.close();
```

Comment: What errors do you see? Have you requested permission to access to external storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of examples available for this

Check this post

[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)

and link

http://open-pim.com/tmp/LazyList.zip

Answer (score 0):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` you'll need to add the permission to write

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Then just get get the path to your filename and make sure your directories exist before trying to write the file to the sdcard.

```
String imageFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/somedirectory/imagename.jpg"
```